# AWS DMS unable to write to MSK target

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-dms, aws-msk

*Note:* self-answered question, because Google didn't shed any light on the problem.

I have configured a Managed Streaming for Kafka target for AWS Data Migration Service, but the migration job fails. Looking at the logs, I see this:

```
2021-11-17T18:45:21 kafka_send_record  (kafka_records.c:88)
2021-11-17T18:50:21 Message delivery failed with Error:[Local: Message timed out] [1026800]  (kafka_records.c:16)
```

I have verified the following:

- Both DMS replication instance and MSK cluster use the same security group, with a "self ingress" rule that allows all traffic, and an egress rule that allows all traffic.
- The endpoint connection test succeeds.
- I can send a message to the MSK topic using the Kafka console producer from an EC2 instance in the same VPC (and receive this message with the console consumer).
- The DMS job succeeds if I change the endpoint to use a self-managed Kafka cluster, running on an EC2 instance in the same VPC.

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that the problem was that I pre-created the topic, with a replication factor of 1, but the default MSK configuration specifies `min.insync.replicas` of 2, which is applied to all created topics.

When DMS sends a message, it requires acks from all in-sync replicas (I'm inferring this, as it's not open-source). This will never succeed if the minimum number of in-sync replicas exceeds the number of actual replicas.

The Kafka console producer, however, [defaults to a single ack](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/tools/ConsoleProducer.scala#L167). This means that it's not a great verification for MSK cluster usability.

Semi-related: the MSK default `default.replication.factor` value is 3, which means that you over-replicate for a 2-node MSK cluster.

Comment: Nice. Think you can accept the answer. To be clear the solutions is to ensure the topic (when created or modified) has a replication factor of 2 or more. Eg. `./kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic my_topc --create --partitions 2 --replication-factor 2`